# O que é mais rápido: Alocação no Stack ou no Heap?

Tags: desempenho, memória, stack, compiladores, heap

Essa pergunta pode soar elementar mas me gerou um bom debate com um colega de trabalho.

Eu sempre que posso faço alocações no `Stack` porque pra mim o crescimento do `Stack` é constante em tempo. E já a performance de alocação em `Heap` depende da complexidade do mesmo no momento tanto para alocação quando para desalocação.

Ao meu ver essa é uma questão que depende muito do compilador que está sendo utilizado. Mas tendo em base `GCC`, qual é o caso? Teria a alocação em `Heap` uma performance baixa comparada com a alocação em `Stack`? Não tem diferença? Ou a diferença é tao minima que não compensa trabalhar com essa micro otimização?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Eficiência**

A alocação em `Stack` é sempre bastante mais rápida que a alocação em `Heap`, pois regra geral corresponde apenas a avançar o `esp`, que é o ponteiro da stack frame corrente na quantidade de bytes desejada, reservando os mesmos para a alocação que se está a fazer. Algo como:

```
sub esp, 4
```

Que iria reservar 4 bytes para o novo elemento no `Stack`

A alocação no `Heap` terá que passar pelo gestor de memória, que só por si já será bem mais lento, mas ainda pode incorrer noutros tipos de situações que penalizam ainda mais a eficiência, tais como fragmentação de memória. Em linguagens sem Garbage Collection, como o C/C++, o que é alocado no `Heap` tem de ser depois manualmente desalocado chamando `free` ou `delete`.

**Vida do objeto**

Existem ainda outras questões tais como a duração de vida do objeto. Não convêm esquecer que se o objeto deve persistir após o método/função terminar terá que ser alocado em Heap. Todo o espaço reservado em Stack para uma função executar é libertado após a mesma retornar.

**Optimizações**

As optimizações são muito dependentes do código em questão. Para além disso o próprio compilador já faz bastantes, podendo até nem declarar determinadas variáveis se achar que não são necessárias. Muitas vezes optimizações prematuras levam a resolver problemas que no código fatorizado final nem existem. Será mais aconselhado optimizar quando vir que é um troço de código critico para a sua aplicação e que consegue ganhar eficiência considerável no mesmo.